# How do I convert this string into a hash?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, hash

The following code returns some cookie data as a string.

```
require 'httparty'

r = HTTParty.get('https://mijn.ing.nl/internetbankieren/SesamLoginServlet')

r.headers
# => {"date"=>["Sat, 26 Jul 2014 19:34:09 GMT"], "cache-control"=>["no-cache", "no-store"], "pragma"=>["no-cache"], "expires"=>["Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"], "content-length"=>["13987"], "set-cookie"=>["sessiontype=mpb; Secure", "aac=742A83A50A4C422C24D6F952C4BF6355; Expires=Sun, 26 Jul 2015 19:34:08 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.ing.nl; Secure", "internetbankierenmi=1777182912.20480.0000; path=/", "TSdb640d=de34831032c17e8b66f123633372a9b341a9773368fccca553d402b1d4efbe89959deba9debace3fe0d47c86e27e0b6b1669bf05; Path=/"], "vary"=>["Accept-Encoding,User-Agent"], "content-type"=>["text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"], "content-language"=>["en"], "connection"=>["close"], "strict-transport-security"=>["max-age=8640000"]}

response_cookies = r.headers['set-cookie']
# => "sessiontype=mpb; Secure, aac=742A83A50A4C422C24D6F952C4BF6355; Expires=Sun, 26 Jul 2015 19:34:08 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.ing.nl; Secure, internetbankierenmi=1777182912.20480.0000; path=/, TSdb640d=de34831032c17e8b66f123633372a9b341a9773368fccca553d402b1d4efbe89959deba9debace3fe0d47c86e27e0b6b1669bf05; Path=/"
```

I want to convert the `response_cookies` String to a Hash I can send along with a POST request.

It should look something like this:

```
{
  "sessiontype"=>"mpb", 
  "aac"=>"7430AEE30A4C42200A45ED316AA03490", 
  "Expires"=>"Sun, 26 Jul 2015 19:34:08 GMT", 
  "Path"=>"/", 
  "Domain"=>".ing.nl", 
  "internetbankierenmi"=>"1777182912.20480.0000", 
  "TSdb640d"=>"de34831032c17e8b66f123633372a9b341a9773368fccca553d402b1d4efbe89959deba9debace3fe0d47c86e27e0b6b1669bf05"
}
```

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: When I set `headers` equal to your value for `r.headers`, and then `response_cookies = headers['set-cookie']`, I find `response_cookies` is an array of four strings, not a string. Please explain or correct.  Why is the value for `"Path"` `"%2F"`?  Why is `"path=/"` (lower case `"p"`) not reflected in your desired result? In future, please don't just dump a bunch of data. Prune the question to its essentials. Instead of `"TSdb640d=de..."` followed by a gazillion characters, you could have just written, say, `"TSdb=d3"`.  And please format so that horizontal scrolling is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [String#scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-scan) and convert the resulting array to hash:

```
s.scan(/([^= ]+)=([^=;]+)(?=;|$)/).to_h
# => {"sessiontype"=>"mpb", "aac"=>"742A83A50A4C422C24D6F952C4BF6355", "Expires"=>"Sun, 26 Jul 2015 19:34:08 GMT", "Path"=>"/", "Domain"=>".ing.nl", "internetbankierenmi"=>"1777182912.20480.0000", "TSdb640d"=>"de34831032c17e8b66f123633372a9b341a9773368fccca553d402b1d4efbe89959deba9debace3fe0d47c86e27e0b6b1669bf05"}
```